# Are there any to-do-list-creating apps that allow for persistent task lists in Notification Center? Does Apple's iOS even allow for this?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, notifications

Apple's iOS Reminders.app has the great functionality that it can list reminders in the Notification Center 24 hours in advance of the actual alert time. This is very useful, since it allows one to swipe down the Notification Center and quickly view what tasks are awaiting future completion, which is, naturally, great for efficient planning purposes -- and, moreover, all this can easily be done without ever having to open up the Reminders app itself.

This functionality, however, seems to be missing from third-party productivity apps. Any apps designed to create to-do lists can seemingly only create an entry in the Notification Center once the alert time has passed, but this creates the typical alert entry with a blue circle to its left -- which does not seem to me to be the most appropriate format (both aesthetically and functionally) for a persistent reminder (compare this to Reminders app entries, which do not have any symbols to the left until after the alert time has passed, at which point the symbol is a white bell rather than a blue circle).

Of course, one can simply use the Reminders app to bypass this problem, but, in my experience, the Reminders app is not ideally suited for daily to-do lists.

So the question is whether there are any apps that have the same Notification-Center functionality as the Reminders app and, if not, whether that is because Apple does not allow for third-party apps to have that functionality (i.e., because that functionality is not available in Apple's Notification Center API). Perhaps some comments can also be made on how to overcome this apparent limitation.

Comment: That is intriguing and something I had never quantified. Not that it matters, but I think I'm first curious why you don't prefer to use the Reminders app to bypass the problem (it even works with Siri)? You certainly have an interesting point that almost all NC entries occurred in the past, with Reminders and Calendar being the main (only?) exceptions.

Comment: It's probably silly, but I tend to associate the Reminders app with just that -- reminding me about irregular tasks that need completion every once in a while. I would prefer to be able to use an app dedicated to creating task/to-do lists for daily planning purposes. I do, however, realize that the distinction is probably idiosyncratic. In any case, I hope that the question about whether third-party apps are even allowed that functionality (I forgot that Calendar has it as well) is still an interesting one in its own right!